# Magento 2: cron group run all crons

Tags: magento2, magento-cron

I have created cron for my custom module using this link http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/config-guide/cron/custom-cron-ref.html

crontab.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Cron:etc/crontab.xsd">
    <group id="test">
        <job name="test" instance="test\Ship\Cron\Observer" method="cronOderSync">
            <schedule>*/5 * * * *</schedule>
        </job>
    </group>
</config>
```

And cron_groups.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Cron:etc/cron_groups.xsd">
    <group id="test">
        <schedule_generate_every>5</schedule_generate_every>
        <schedule_ahead_for>4</schedule_ahead_for>
        <schedule_lifetime>4</schedule_lifetime>
        <history_cleanup_every>10</history_cleanup_every>
        <history_success_lifetime>60</history_success_lifetime>
        <history_failure_lifetime>600</history_failure_lifetime>
        <use_separate_process>1</use_separate_process>
    </group>
</config>
```

So I have two issues:

```
1) when I run bin/magento cron:run [--group="<cron group name>"], it run all crons file.

2) I have setup schedule in cron_group.xml file, but it did not run cron every 5 minutes automatically.
```

Answer (score 0):

Run below code and check:

```
bin/magento cron:run [--group="test"]
```

Comment: I run this command but run all cron.

Comment: @Priya change group id from " <group id="test">" to " <group id="default">" and test please

Answer (score 0):

Remove the brackets
bin/magento cron:run --group="test"